# How to add a sub-status (error code) to a REST response in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, rest

I'm using Spring in a RESTful application and I throw a few HTTP 401 exceptions when access is being denied.

Essentially, I'm simply throwing one or more exceptions annotated by:

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)
```

Which returns something like this:

```
{
   "timestamp": 1434805699008,
   "status": 401,
   "error": "Unauthorized",
   "message": "[ERR:02-011] Access to '/user/account/{id}' is rejected!",
   "path": "/user/account/{id}"
}
```

The problem is that there are many sub-reasons for throwing an HTTP 401, such as API-KEY is malformed, API-KEY is invalid (not hex, too short, too long), API-KEY has expired, etc.

I would like the client to be able to parse such sub-status.  I would like to be able to receive something like this:

```
{
   "timestamp": 1434805699008,
   "status": 401,
   "code": 12011,
   "error": "Unauthorized",
   "message": "[ERR:12-011] Access to '/user/account/{id}' is rejected!",
   "path": "/user/account/{id}"
}
```

Where there would be a "`code`" property that could be consumed by the client.  I do not want to resort to parsing string messages such as my "[ERR:02-011]" which is bad practice.

I tried extending all my exceptions with an `AbstractWebException` which has a `code` variable with proper getter and setter methods.  But this does not seem to end up being serialized with the rest of the exception (not too sure why).

I want to keep it simple!

Thanks for any advice and any help.

---

Some code:

```
public abstract class AbstractWebException extends RuntimeException {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   private int errorCode = 0;

   public AbstractWebException(String message) {
      super(message);
   }

   public AbstractWebException(int errorCode, String message) {
      super(message);
      setErrorCode(errorCode);
   }

   public void setErrorCode(int errorCode) {
      this.errorCode = errorCode;
   }

   public int getErrorCode() {
      return errorCode;
   }
}
```

... and...

```
/**
 * <b>HTTP 401 - Unauthorized</b>
 */
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)
public class UnauthorizedException extends AbstractWebException {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   public UnauthorizedException(String message) {
      super(message);
   }
}
```

Comment: Which, the exception?  I can only show code which can easily be "cleaned up" and won't reveal client information and/or their intellectual property.

Comment: The code of the exception. The code that transforms the exceptions into this JSON body.

Comment: Ah, I think I'm seeing something.  There is one exception thrown in a controller and the rest are handled in a filter.  It seems as though the filter code is using 'response.sendError(SC_BAD_REQUEST, "some message")' instead of throwing the UnauthorizedException.  I tried replacing the sendError() with a throw new UnauthorizedException but the filter seems to be overriding the exception with its own... weird!

Comment: Some component, probably annotated with @ControllerAdvice, is responsible for transforming exceptions into a JSON response body. That's where you need to change something.

Comment: Is there a way to get the filter to return to the client the exception thrown... like a controller does?

Comment: I created a test controller and a new web API which simply throws my UnauthorizedException to test without the complexities of my app and the errorCode never gets serialized.  So I'm going to have to dig to see how I can get it serialized.

Comment: @JBNizet ok I will try the ControllerAdvice you referred to.  I don't know what it is so I'll do a bit of research.  Thank you!

Comment: I'm not advising you to use that. I guess you must *already* use it, and that's where the exception is transformed to JSON. Find the usages of your exception in your project to know where that actually happens.

Comment: 50 % of your payload contains redundant information the client already knows: status code, reason phrase, path. timestamp. Return only what the client does *not* know.

Comment: @Michael-O, I don't return any of that stuff, Spring handles it.  All I do is throw an exception with the message.  I'm not sure what you mean by client already knows?  He knows because Spring gives it to them otherwise client would not know.

Comment: @Jeach The response has a header for status code and reason phrase. The client knows what URL he called in the request, and when he called it. Sending it back is probably a waste of bandwidth.

Comment: @EricStein, exactly.

Comment: @EricStein, I agree but that's Spring's automagic at work.  I'm relatively new to Spring so I'm not sure if it's config or what.  I'll have to look at it at some time.  Thanks.

Comment: @Jeach Yeah, I know it's not you. :-) Sometimes frameworks try to be "helpful" in ways that aren't.